# Unable to Output Chinese Characters in CLion Using MSYS2 MinGW64 Despite UTF-8 Settings

Tags: c++, utf-8, clion, msys2

I am developing a C++ application in CLion using MSYS2's MinGW64 compiler. My project involves outputting Chinese characters, but despite setting everything to UTF-8 (Global/File/Terminal encodings in CLion, source file encoding, and PowerShell terminal encoding), the characters are not displayed correctly. They appear as garbled text or question marks in the output.

Ensured all encodings in CLion (Global, File, Terminal) are set to UTF-8.
Verified the source file is saved in UTF-8 encoding.
Changed PowerShell's encoding to UTF-8 using chcp 65001.
Set LANG and LC_ALL environment variables to en_US.UTF-8 in Windows.
Experimented with handling and printing strings using std::wstring and std::wcout in C++.
I expected these steps to allow Chinese characters to be displayed correctly in the output, but they are still appearing incorrectly. It seems like there's a missing piece in the configuration or a compatibility issue with the tools and environment I'm using.

Comment: What version of Windows are you on?  (Older versions of Windows do not support UTF-8 end-to-end including `cin` and `cout`.)  Since you did not provide your code, I cannot tell if you did `SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);`.  Does MSYS2's MinGW64 support UTF-8?  If not, you might want to try Visual Studio Community edition instead.

Comment: Please show your code as a [mcve], so we can try running it ourselves.

Comment: @Eljay *"Does MSYS2's MinGW64 support UTF-8?"* Yes.

Comment: Set CLion aside. Fire up Notepad++. Create a hello-world `hello.cpp` program that prints a Chinese greeting. Do absolutely nothing whatsoever with locales, code pages or any of that stuff, just make sure your file encoding is UTF-8. Compile with `c:\msys2\mingw64\bin\g++ -static hello.cpp -o hello.exe` (use your actual msys install path).  Run `hello.exe` in Windows terminal. Is the output correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add it after introducing the header file <windows.h> before the function that outputs Chinese

```cpp
SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
```